onnxruntime::qnn::QnnModel::ParseGraphInputOrOutput Dynamic shape is not supported yet, for output: /model.12/Concat_output_0_QuantizeLinear_Output
I am trying to run yolov5 onnx model in Qualcomm NPU using OnnxRuntime QNN execution provider.
I am getting this error while intializing the sesssion. ort.InferenceSession()
ParseGraphInputOrOutput Dynamic shape is not supported yet
options = ort.SessionOptions()
options.add_session_config_entry("session.disable_cpu_ep_fallback", "1")
options.add_session_config_entry("ep.context_enable", "1")
options.add_session_config_entry("ep.context_embed_mode", "0")


sess = ort.InferenceSession('yolov5s.onnx', sess_options=options,
                                       providers=["QNNExecutionProvider"],
                                       provider_options=[{"backend_path": "QnnHtp.dll"}])

